# UWP App direct boot from Media

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, xaml, uwp

We have an embedded product that requires the following separate media requirements for the application. Each application must be stored separately upon removable media to enable verification of the disk contents to match a recorded digital signature.

For more understanding, the current install base simply has a boot exe application on the OS drive that is called on boot rather than explorer.exe. This simple app looks to the disk name, and then will fire off a EXE file on the disk. The current applications are written in .Net with the OS disk having all the framework and OS files needed installed. The removable media just includes the application and related DLLs and such for the application

Question, with Windows 10 based UWP applications using VS2017 for development it appears that this is going to be problematic. The EXE will not simply activate with a start script to fire the EXE off as before.

Is there any way to develop a UWP app with just the core application resources deployed as described above on the removable media disk?

Simply activate a UWP app on a removable drive without having to install an APP?

Comment: Do you mean you want to install the UWP app in a disk, then when the media disk connect to the compute the UWP app will run? If so, you can not implement this effect in UWP app, since UWP app run sandboxed, it will be installed on the your device specific location with specific application data folder.

Comment: Yes, it will be written once to a compact flash disk. That disk is then signed and inserted into the Embedded Computer. Every time the embedded Computer boots it will boot straight to this application folder that resides on the Compact Flash Disk. I am trying to find a way to bypass the sandbox to enable the above to work.

Comment: UWP app's sandbox environment has many limitations compared to the Win32 app and UWP is unsuited for your this function.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Unfortunate, as UWP would be a good solution in our industry if it just had slightly more flexibility on a couple issues.

Comment: If you need some features in UWP, you can submit the feature request to the UserVoice website:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform.